# What is the wavelength of red light in vacuum?

Tags: waves, electromagnetic-radiation, visible-light, frequency, wavelength

[According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red),

> It has a dominant wavelength of approximately 625–740 nanometres.

However, I'm not sure in which medium this wavelength was measured. Was this wavelength measured in a vacuum? What is the wavelength of red light in a vacuum?

Comment: Yes it is the wavelength in vacuum. but also in air, since it is a range of wavelengths

Comment: For reference, the refractive index of air is roughly 1.0003, ever so slightly larger than that of vacuum, but close enough to 1.0000 for all practical purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loosely, it doesn't matter whether it is air or vacuum. The index of refraction of air is about $1.0003$ at visible wavelengths. That means $\lambda_{vacuum}/\lambda_{air} \approx 1.0003$. Not enough to notice.

Of course, some people are interested in precision. They would use the value in vacuum. Or perhaps the value in whatever medium light is traveling through in their case.

Comment: @SolomonSlow - Thank you ! Fixed.